# Is there a tool I can use to discover available web services on a URL or IP?

Tags: web-services, soap, ws-discovery

I need to find out what web services are available on a particular server. I know this host is using some flavor of SOAP.

Is there a tool that can show what services (methods) are available from this host.

Answer (score 2):

If they are using SOAP they should expose a Web Service Definition Language ([WSDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl)) document.  This will describe all available methods and the data-types needed to call and parse the responses.

If the service is not meant to be public not sure of any technique other than simply search for a descriptor document somewhere on their domain.

Comment: I know about WSDL, but what is the way of getting this doc if there is no specified registry.

Comment: like i said if you've not been told where the WSDL is finding it is going to be a bit tricky.